# General solution of trigonmetric equations

Tags: trigonometry

Is there any formula for general solution of equations like $|\cos \alpha| \leq \beta$ ?

Specifically, $|\cos x| \leq \frac{1}{2}, x \in [0,1]$ ? I want all the values of $x$  satisfying the above in terms of $n \in \Bbb N$.

Comment: Is $\beta$ fixed?

Answer (score 0):

$$|\cos \alpha|\leq\beta\\
\implies \cos \alpha\leq\beta\text{ AND }\cos \alpha\geq-\beta\\
\implies \alpha\leq\arccos\beta\text{ AND }\alpha\geq\arccos(-\beta)\\
\implies \alpha\in[\arccos(-\beta),\arccos\beta]$$
Now, for $|\cos (x)|\leq\dfrac{1}{2}$, there is no solution with $x\in[0,1]. See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%7Ccos+x%7C%5Cleq+1%2F2) for all the solutions.

Comment: I have added something.

Comment: @aaaaaa I, too, have changed my answer.